# JSONP not working on the page

Tags: callback, jsonp, wikipedia-api

I have a page where i am using the `wikipedia api`. But since i cannot use `JSON` for cross domain restrictions i use `JSONP`. My code looks like this

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function res(data){
  alert(data);
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=api&callback=res&limit=10&namespace=0&format=jsonfm">
</script>
</body>
```

here i am providing the callback function named `res` in the url. As i saw in firebug the response came as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>MediaWiki API Result</title>
</head>
<body>
<br />
<small>
You are looking at the HTML representation of the JSON format.<br />
HTML is good for debugging, but probably is not suitable for your application.<br />
See <a href='http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API'>complete documentation</a>, or
<a href='/w/api.php'>API help</a> for more information.
</small>
<pre>
res([
&quot;api&quot;,
[
&quot;API&quot;,
&quot;Apiales&quot;,
&quot;Apiaceae&quot;,
&quot;Apia&quot;,
&quot;Apicomplexa&quot;,
&quot;Apicomplexa lifecycle stages&quot;,
&quot;Apidae&quot;,
&quot;APIA Leichhardt Tigers&quot;,
&quot;Apical membrane&quot;,
&quot;Apical consonant&quot;
]
])
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This means that the server is sending the response enclosed in the callback function `res` but this function is not executed by the browser(the `alert` is not being called).I am using firefox 5. Whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says it right there in the response:

> You are looking at the HTML representation of the JSON format.
>   HTML is good for debugging, but probably is not suitable for your
>   application.

try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=api&callback=res&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json">
```

Comment: then how do i get the `json` format. i am passing `format` parameter as json in the url.

Comment: You're passing jsonfm. Just try what I posted. It should work.

Comment: that worked. well on the wikipedia api documentation they specified as `jsonfm` so i thought it means json format. can u tell why they say it jsonfm. here is the [link](www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats)

Comment: It really is weird... The example they provide uses jsonfm... No idea.

Comment: look at this page, you should find an answer there: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Comment: i read that. cant seem to figure out why they call it `jsonfm`. anyway thanks for the help

Comment: quote -> "Changing format to jsonfm will return a "pretty-printed" HTML result good for debugging."
Source: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page